# Outputting prime numbers in given ranges

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes

I coded an algorithm which shows prime numbers in the ranges provided by the user. The first line states the number of test cases. Example:

INPUT

```
2
1 10
1 5
```

OUTPUT

```
2
3
5
7

2
3
5
```

t - number of cases, n and m is the range
(t<=10)
m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space

And here is my problem, algorithm works fine, but website which test this, shows- too slow. I need less than 6s !

In my opinion, problem is in method addPrimeNumbers.

```
class PrimeNumbers{

    private static int m = 0;
    private static int n = 0;
    private static int t = 0;
    private static int i = 0;
    private static String beforeSeparate;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static List<int[]> scope = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        t = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
        if (checkT(t)) {

            beforeSeparate = sc.nextLine();

            if (separate(beforeSeparate).length == 2) {
                m = separate(beforeSeparate)[0];
                n = separate(beforeSeparate)[1];
                i++;
            }
            if (checkM(m) && checkN(n) && t != 1 && n - m <= 100000) {
                int firstScope[] = {m,n};
                scope.add(firstScope);
                repeatReader();
            }
            else if (t == 1 && checkM(m) && checkN(n) && n - m <= 100000){
                int firstScope[] = {m,n};
                scope.add(firstScope);
            }
            for (int[] aScope : scope) {
                addPrimeNumbers(aScope[0], aScope[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void repeatReader(){
        beforeSeparate = sc.nextLine();
        if (separate(beforeSeparate).length == 2){
            m = separate(beforeSeparate)[0];
            n = separate(beforeSeparate)[1];
            i++;
            int nextScope[] = {m,n};
            scope.add(nextScope);
            if (i < t){
                repeatReader();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addPrimeNumbers(int i, int i1) {
        String result = "";

        for (int j = i; j <= i1 ; j++) {

            int counters = 0;
            for (int num = j; num >= i ; num--) {

                if (j % num == 0){
                    counters = counters +1;
                }
            }
            if (counters == 2){
                result = result + j + "\n";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static boolean checkT(int i){
        return i > 0 && i <= 10;
    }

    private static boolean checkMinMax(int i) {
        return i >= 1 && i <= 1000000000;
    }

    private static boolean checkM(int i) {
        return checkMinMax(i) && n > 0 && i <= n;
    }

    private static boolean checkN(int i) {
        return checkMinMax(i) && m > 0 && i >= m;
    }

    private static int[] separate(String i){
        String twoValue[] = i.split(" ");

        m = Integer.parseInt(twoValue[0]);
        n = Integer.parseInt(twoValue[1]);
        return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(twoValue[0]), Integer.parseInt(twoValue[1])};
    }
}
```

Someone know, how to speed up this ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: Do you happen to know what input causes the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before addressing the performance problem I would like to make some
general remarks:

- You validate the input values (`t`, `m`, `n`), but invalid numbers are
  simply ignored. For a programming challenge I would assume that the
  input values *are* in the specific ranges. However, *if* you decide to
  check the validity then an invalid input should produce an error message
  or program exception.

  Also the check is unnecessary complicated: `m` and `n` are passed to
  functions `checkM` and `checkN`, but those functions also refer to
  the class variables `m` and `n` directly. This could be simplified to

  ```
  if (1 <= m && m <= n && n <= 1000000000 && n - m <= 100000) { ... }
  ```

  Even better, define and use constants for those limits.
- The recursive function `repeatReader` is used to handle all test
  cases (but *only* if there is more than one test case). This seems
  unnecessary complicated to me, a simple loop would suffice.
- The logic to get two integers from the input line is duplicated
  in `main` and `repeatReader`.
- Several variables are declared as static class variables, but
  needed only locally in a function (such as `m`, `n`, `beforeSeparate`).
- There is no need to store all ranges in an array first, you can
  read each range and then produce the corresponding output.
- `Scanner.nextInt()` can be used to read the input into integers 
  directly.
- In `addPrimeNumbers` you can print all found prime numbers directly,
  without concatenating them to a string first.

So the overall structure could be simplified to

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PrimeNumbers {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numTests = sc.nextInt();
        for (int test = 1; test <= numTests; test++) {
            int m = sc.nextInt();
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            printPrimesInRange(m, n);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void printPrimesInRange(int low, int hi) {
        // Print prime numbers in the range low...hi
    }
}
```

Note that

```
       for (int num = j; num >= i ; num--) {
```

in `addPrimeNumbers` should be

```
       for (int num = j; num >= 1 ; num--) {
```

otherwise the result is not correct for ranges not starting at 1.

With respect to performance: Your function counts *all* divisors
of a number, but

- one can stop the test if *any* non-trivial divisor has been found,
- any non-prime number \$ n \$ has a divisor which is \$ \le \sqrt n \$

Therefore this

```
    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        for (int j = 2; j <= limit; j++) {
            if (n % j == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void printPrimesInRange(int low, int hi) {
        for (int n = low; n <= hi; ++n) {
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }
```

would already improve the performance because the primality check
for each number \$ n \$ is reduced from \$ O(n) \$ to \$ O(\sqrt n) \$.

For the range `100000 200000` this reduced the time from 43 seconds
to approx 0.3 seconds on my 3.5 GHz Intel Core i5 iMac, measured with

```
$ time java PrimeNumbers < input > output
```

and for the range `999900000 1000000000` I measured 0.7 seconds.

So this might be sufficiently fast to pass the challenge.
For even better performance, use sieving methods like the
(segmented) sieve of Eratosthenes (see for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segmented-sieve/).

Comment: This is a great answer and well done.  However I wonder if you tested the output.  Specifically I think that `isPrime()` might wrongly identify 2 as not prime.  Didn't test it, but that how it looks.  I might be wrong.

Comment: @markspace: You are right, there was an error in the calculation of the upper limit for the divisor check. Apparently I did not inspect the (initial) output carefully enough. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: No worries.  Your code and answer look great otherwise.

Comment: your algorithm allow more than 10 cases ?

Comment: @jackfield: Yes, it works with arbitrary many test cases. You can check the value of `numTests` if you want, but I don't find that necessary.

Answer (score 4):

A prime number has only two factors, 1 and itself.  However, counting factors -- as you do -- is not an efficient way to detect primes.  A more efficient way is to look for factors in [2, n-1].  Any factor in that range indicates a composite number with three or more factors, so the search can be stopped at that point.  As @Martin R pointed out, the search only need cover [2, sqrt(n)] to find the smaller of any pair of factors.  In pseudocode this looks something like:

```
boolean isPrime(n) {

  for i in 2 to sqrt(n) do
    if (n MOD i == 0)
      return false  // n is not prime, it has a third factor.
    endif
  endfor

  // n is prime if we get this far.
  return true

}
```

There is a further efficiency with even numbers.  If any even number is a factor of n, then 2 is also a factor.  Hence, once you have tested for 2 as a factor, you don't need to check any other even numbers as a factor.  This will roughly halve the runtime.

```
boolean isPrime(n) {

  // Even n
  if (n MOD 2 == 0)
    return n == 2  // 2 is the only even prime number.
  endif

  // Odd n
  for i in 3 to sqrt(n) step 2 do
    if (n MOD i == 0)
      return false  // n has a third factor so it is not prime.
    endif
  endfor

  // n is an odd prime if we get this far.
  return true

}
```

As a minor point, if you are going to check the given input parameters, it is probably better style to use a single `checkParameters()` method, given that the checks are so simple.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering, the following does NOT work.  It takes too long at roughly the point shown in the code:

```
public class PrimeSieve {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      BigInteger num = BigInteger.ZERO;
//      BigInteger end = new BigInteger( "1000000000" );
      BigInteger end = new BigInteger( "1000000" );
      while( num.compareTo( end ) < 0 ) {
         num = num.nextProbablePrime();
      }
      System.out.println( num );
   }

}
```

Output:

```
run:
1000003
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```